# Cross fading between three divs in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations, keyframe

I've been working on cross-fading between three different images for a "twinkling" effect, but discovered I actually need to do this with three different divs so I can use the "background-repeat" property. The problem is I can't seem to figure out how to modify the code to work with divs instead of images.

Here's the code I've been using that works with images:

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes twinkle {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes twinkle {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes twinkle {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}

#starrysky img {
        position: top left fixed;
        width:900px;
    }

#starrysky img:nth-child(2)  {
    opacity: .9;
    -webkit-animation: twinkle 1.25s ease-in alternate infinite;
    -moz-animation: twinkle 1.25s ease-in alternate infinite;
    animation: twinkle 1.25s ease-in alternate infinite;
    transition-delay: 2s;
}

#starrysky img:nth-child(3)  {
    opacity: .9;
    -webkit-animation: twinkle 1.75s ease-in alternate infinite;
    -moz-animation: twinkle 1.75s ease-in alternate infinite;
    animation: twinkle 1.75s ease-in alternate infinite;
    transition-delay: 3s;
}

#starrysky img:nth-child(4)  {
    opacity: .7;
    -webkit-animation: twinkle 2.5s ease-in alternate infinite;
    -moz-animation: twinkle 2.5s ease-in alternate infinite;
    animation: twinkle 2.5s ease-in alternate infinite;
    transition-delay: 2s;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="starrysky">
    <img src="arcticnomoon1.jpg;">
    <img src="arcticnomoon2.jpg">
    <img src="arcticnomoon3.jpg">
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated! I'm hoping to be able to do this without jQuery, or if I must, very simple jQuery. :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you are on the right track, you're just positioning the images in the #starrysky div a bit wrong :)

Here's an example

```css
@-webkit-keyframes twinkle {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes twinkle {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes twinkle {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}
#starrysky { 
    position: relative; 
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#starrysky img {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

#starrysky img{
    opacity: .9;
    -webkit-animation: twinkle 1.25s ease-in alternate infinite;
    -moz-animation: twinkle 1.25s ease-in alternate infinite;
    animation: twinkle 1.25s ease-in alternate infinite;
    transition-delay: 2s;
}

#starrysky img:nth-child(2)  {
    opacity: .9;
    -webkit-animation: twinkle 1.75s ease-in alternate infinite;
    -moz-animation: twinkle 1.75s ease-in alternate infinite;
    animation: twinkle 1.75s ease-in alternate infinite;
    transition-delay: 3s;
}
```

```html
<div id="starrysky">
    <img src="http://www.southernhillsanimalhospital.com/sites/site-1450/images/kittens.jpg" />
    <img src="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/kitten/kitten-2.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! I was actually hoping to find a way to use divs instead of images instead so I could make use of the background-repeat property. So for example,

`<div id="starrysky">
    <div style="background-image: url(http://www.southernhillsanimalhospital.com/sites/site-1450/images/kittens.jpg); background-repeat:repeat-x;">
<div style="background-image: url(http://dreamatico.com/data_images/kitten/kitten-2.jpg); background-repeat:repeat-x;">
</div>`

Comment: Hmmm, why do you need to use "background-repeat"?

Comment: I'd like the image to go across the full width of the page, even as the page resizes. :\

Comment: Then you just need to set the container element (<div id="starrysky"></div> to be 100% wide :) EDIT: and of course the images inside it need to be 100% wide too.

Comment: Hmm... but I don't necessarily want my image to be huge... I just want it to repeat across the horizontal axis?

Comment: Ok, then you can put those div's inside the starrysky div, set the background images for them and animate divs :)